# Помогите с ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хотел сделать элементароного бота что-то не работает хелп

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("5747886868:AAGMI_NYx8VhJ-HFXrlus2WAuQcXzX_mmx4") 


@bot.message_handler(contetn_types=['text'])
def send_welcom(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет как дела?</b>', parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Посоветую вам удалять токен бота при показе кода бота третим лицам, иначе кто-то может его использовать в не самых лучших целей, а сейчас лучше перегенерировать токен бота

Answer (score 2):

У вас была ошибка с типо хадлера, вы препутали местами две буквы

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) #  Вот тут была ошибка
def send_welcom(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет как дела?</b>', parse_mode='html')
```